# How to use variable in extractor with unescaped body?

Tags: regex, jmeter, extractor

I have a JMeter user variable x = abc and an extractor from a response, with regex = abc\d, using the unescaped body option.

If I try to change the regex to ${x}\d, it doesn't work, however, if I change body type to normal body with escape characters, then it works fine.

For better readability, I want to keep the unescaped body, please advise what is the correct syntax.

Comment: If the trouble is caused by `\d`, try  using `${x}[0-9]`

Comment: I have already tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: I was able to get my test case working with `${test}:([0-9]*)`. (this is using JMeter 2.13 (although I'd be surprised if we lost functionality with 3.0))

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I will try it on 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jmeter uses `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4` on response if you choose Body (unescaped) option

But at the end variable is already "decoded" without choosing this option, meaning `&nbsp;` -> space, so you can ignore this option.